# How can I fix a function whose code has been "ungrouped" in VBScript?

Tags: function, vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I've been using Unified Functional Testing to run an automated test. Everything was going okay for weeks, but then I got an error message saying that my function library was invalid, moments after running a different test just fine. Upon further investigation, I noticed that the second half of my function library had functions with code that was no longer grouped within a function (denoted by the grey line along the left side of the code, directly to the right of line numbers).

I am unable to post snippets of code unfortunately because it is not my own property.

Answer (score 3):

"`denoted by the grey line along the left side of the code, directly to the right of line numbers`", this means those lines of code are commented out by someone. Now if you want to use those code, you need to uncomment it.

There are two ways:

- 1)  Remove "**`'`**" from beginning of all the lines.
- 2)  Open the function library file in UFT.
    Select all the lines covering your commented code, and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

Either of these options will uncomment your code and you'll be able to use it.